# Log - add to every file?

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, custom-component

I would like to use JLog on different files in my component.

At the moment I'm adding this to my `__contruct` method:

```
JLog::addLogger( array( 'text_file' => 'com_bestia.log.php' ) );
```

But is it possible to add this only once to one file and use it on different other files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you're trying to do is possible cause the component won't know when to, and when not to log errors.

What you can do is, load the JLog class and tell your component to log all errors, like so

```
JLoader::register('JLog', JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/joomla/log/log.php');

JLog::addLogger(
    array(
        'text_file' => 'com_bestia.log.php'
    ),
    JLog::ALL,
    'com_bestia'
);
```

Then, let's say (for example) you want to check if a file exists and want to log an error if it doesn't exist:

```
if (JFile::exists('path_to_file'))
{
    // import the file
}
else
{
    JLog::add('File does not exist', JLog::WARNING, 'com_bestia');
}
```